# Avoiding rJava related System Exit on ctrl+c when using R in terminal

Tags: java, r, jvm, rjava

[Simon Urbanek](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rosuda.devel/1368) and [others](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-March/052838.html) have  indicated that to prevent `ctrl+c` from causing `R` to quit, one `"needs to add -Xrs java option so the JVM doesn't steal SIGINT from R"`

**My question is Where should this `-Xrs` flag be added?**  Clearly not when calling `library(rJava)`.  Perhaps on install?

```
> is.friends(Me, Java)
[1] FALSE
```

(I rarely call `rJava`, rather it's normally called simply as a dependency, by eg `XLconnect`.  Nevertheless, if I hit `ctrl+c` to attempt to break a run in `R`, the entire program quits.)

Answer (score 2):

you can pass parameters to the JVM just like you do to a command line Java process via
rJava options support than you load your library. For example:

```
## sets the maximum Java heap size to 1024
options (java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m" ) 
## to prevent the Java runtime environment handling 
## exception signals such SIGSEGV and SIGABRT
options (java.parameters = "-Xrs" )
```

Then you load library as usual:

```
library ( XLConnect )
```

**EDIT**

If a package is loading `rJava`  you can specify these flags:

```
.jinit(classpath="myClasses.jar", parameters="-Xmx512m")
```

Comment: If a package is loading `rJava` with `import(rJava)` in `NAMESPACE` is there a way to specify these flags?

Comment: For packages, it is recommended to use `.jpackage` to initiate the package `onLoad` instead of using `.jinit`